# What level are the spells the Penumbra (and other) Bloodline feats add to your spells known?

Tags: feats, dnd-3e

The Penumbra Bloodline feat (Dragon #325) adds a spell to your spells known for each spell level. For some of the spells, the spells are added at the spell level they are listed as in the PHB. However, a few are added at other spell levels. These spells are:
- Shadow Walk (Sor/Wiz 7, gained at 6);
- Greater Shadow Evocation (Sor/Wiz 6, gained at 8);
- Etherealness (Clr 6, Sor/Wiz 8, gained at 9)

Other Bloodline feats have similar discrepancies between the spell levels in the PHB and the listed levels.

As what spell level should I treat these spells for spending spell slots, DCs etc.? Should they be treated as the spell levels listed in the PHB, or does the Bloodline feat overrule these levels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spells don’t have intrinsic levels—they only have the level they appear at *on a particular list*. Different lists can have the same spell at different levels—consider *identify*, a 1st-level spell for sorcerers and wizards, as well as [cloistered clerics](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/variantCharacterClasses.htm#clericVariantCloisteredCleric), but for those who access it through the Magic domain—a non-cloistered cleric, perhaps—it is a 2nd-level spell. *Dispel magic* is another example—3rd-level for clerics, sorcerers, and wizards, by 4th-level for druids.

Likewise, for a sorcerer or wizard, *shadow walk* is a 7th-level spell. For someone casting it through the Penumbra Bloodline feat, it’s a 6th-level spell. That means it requires a 6th-level slot, its DC is 16 + any relevant bonuses, it consumes 6 levels’ worth of *spell turning*’s protection, and so on.